# NSJSONSerialization returns NSNumber(double) causes failure comparing to NSNumber(Int64)

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I have an Int64 (long-long) uniqueID passed as a number in a JSON file.

`{ "id1" : 4627596562884205957 }`

The `NSJSONSerialization` always returns an `NSNumber (double)` in the NSDictionary property. This should be an Int64 number `NSNumber (long-long)`, as the double loses a few digits of needed precision.

It causes a failure, as the code is comparing the deserialized value (double) against the proper values (Int64), and for cases where the two numbers are very close, but still different, they compare as equal, which is the wrong logic.

Can `NSJSONSerialization` be configured to return the proper `NSNumber(long-long)` for this property, instead of the incorrect `double`?

Is it OK to pull the `long-long` value out of a `NSNumber(double)`, then force it back into a new `NSNumber(long-long)`? It seems to work, but I don't trust it.

The following shows the error.

```
- (void) doJSONDoubleVsInt64Comparison
{
    // our primary Int64
    int64_t     aId1 = 4627596562884205957;

    // put it into a JSON string, then read it into a dictionary.
    NSString    *jsonInputString    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ \"id1\" : %lld }", aId1];
    NSData      *jsonData           = [jsonInputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:false];
    NSDictionary *asDictionary      = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    // the number after being deserialized from the JSON string
    NSNumber    *id1Number  = [asDictionary objectForKey:@"id1"];

    // the NSNumber is of type 'double' (not long-long as expected)
    [self logNSNumber:id1Number named:@"id1"];


    // get a DIFFERENT Int64 that varies only slightly
    int64_t     aId2        = 4627596562884205592;
    NSNumber    *id2Number  = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:aId2];

    // This is of type Int64 (long-long) as expected.
    [self logNSNumber:id2Number named:@"id2"];

    // id1 and id2 are not equal numbers, but this comparison returns TRUE - why?
    if( [id1Number isEqualToNumber:id2Number] )
    {
        // we incorrectly hit this condition.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: id1 and id2 were reported to be equal, but they are different numbers.");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"OK: id1 and id2 are not equal, as expected.");
    }

    // pull the long-long from the double - force it to be an Int64
    NSNumber *id1NumberAsInt64 = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:id1Number.longLongValue];

    // the comparison now works.
    [self logNSNumber:id1NumberAsInt64 named:@"id1AsInt64"];

    if( [id1NumberAsInt64 isEqualToNumber:id2Number] )
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: id1 and id2 were reported to be equal, but they are different.");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"OK: id1 and id2 are not equal, as expected.");
    }
}


- (void)logNSNumber:(NSNumber *)aNumber named:(NSString *)name
{
    CFNumberType numberType = CFNumberGetType((CFNumberRef)aNumber);

    switch ( numberType )
    {
        case kCFNumberSInt64Type:
            NSLog(@"%@ returned as an Int64", name); // does NOT hit this
            break;

        case kCFNumberDoubleType:
            NSLog(@"%@ returned as a  double", name); // hits this
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"%@ NumberType = %ld", name, numberType );
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your number is serialized and deserialized as expected?

Comment: Or just compare long long instead of compare NSNumber.

Comment: @Kreiri I didn't check serialized, but from the NSNumber (double), the NSNumber(long-long) value seems to have all of the digits that were in the original JSON. I can't trust that the long-long value is valid though, as it is a NSNumber(double) and that does NOT contain all of the digits, which is why it failed the equality test with an NSNumber(long-long).

Comment: @Genecode Just doing the long-long comparison also doesn't really help, as again I don't trust that value is defined to contain all the digits I need. Until I find a better solution, I am in fact extracting the long-long from the NSNumber(double) and recreating the correct NSNumber(long-long). It works, but isn't defined to work that way AFAICT.